# Visual Studio using C# cannot find web3.Miner.Start.SendRequestAsync

Tags: mining, nethereum, c#

The active using statements of the code are:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Nethereum.Web3;
using Nethereum.Web3.Accounts;
using Nethereum.ABI.FunctionEncoding.Attributes;
using Nethereum.Contracts;
using Nethereum.Hex.HexConvertors;
using Nethereum.RPC.Eth.DTOs; //using Nethereum.Geth;
```

The lint in Microsoft Visual C# 2017 cannot find the function:

```
web3.Miner.Start.SendRequestAsync(6);
```

It flags Miner as not a member of `web3`.

Note: I declared `web3` prior in the code as:

```
var web3 = new Web3(myAccount);
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

The new version of Nethereum separated the shared RPC APIs, from the Client specific APIs and functionality provided by Geth and Parity.

To interact with the Geth client Miner, you need now to add the nuget package Nethereum.Geth, and use the Web3Geth class instead, not the Web3 class:

```
var web3 = new Web3Geth(myAccount);
web3.Miner.Start.SendRequestAsync(6);
```